# Find the value of $c$ such that $h(k(x))=0$ has equal roots, where $h(x)=5x+2$ and $k(x)=cx^2-x+2$

Tags: roots, discriminant

First I rearranged the equation:

$$h(k(x))=5(cx^2-x+2)+2=0$$
$$5cx^2-5x+12=0$$

So the next step would be to set the discriminant equal to $0$:

$$25-240c=0$$
$$c=\frac{5}{48}$$

Would $\frac{5}{48}$  be the value of $c$?

Comment: Seems okay.. why the doubt?

Comment: Yes correct....

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters confirmed, you're correct that $c=\frac{5}{48}$. The resulting quadratic equation will have one root of multiplicity two, which is $x=4.8$.